# Perform browser search from command-line

Tags: bash, macos, shell, command-line, terminal

I would like to run a single terminal command to open a Firefox (my default browser) and perform a search. For example:

```
$ firefox lord of the rings
```

would open a new Firefox tab and search the term "lord of the rings". Similarly:

```
$ firefox https://amazon.com
```

would open a new Firefox tab and load amazon.com.

I know that I can run the command:

```
$ open -a firefox <url>
```

But this does not work with search queries (only urls). Any tips on how to accomplish this are appreciated.

Comment: I recommend you think about how you might construct a shell script to create a search URL and launch your browser at that URL. Many of us could write such a thing, but that wouldn't help you learn how, and improving your programming skills is what StackOverflow is all about. Show us what you've got, we'll help you through any challenges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox on it's own does not query/search the web. You search by using a website that has search capabilities like google.com or bing.com ... so you can simply open a bing.com URL with urlencoded search string.. which will open firefox with the results:

Example:

```
firefox 'https://www.bing.com/search?q=lord+of+the+rings'
```

Comment: he really went with bing for this example